# java output must have 6 numbers on output al the time

Tags: java

The below code will generate 6 random numbers, but on the output it will display 4, 5 or 6 numbers. i need to have six numbers all the time for my assessment. can someone please guide me to what i need to change to get the output consistent.
Thanks.

```
package net.javavideotutorials.assignment1;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class LotteryNumberGenerator 
    {
        public static <generateLotteryNumbers> void main(String[] args) 
    {

        int capacity = 6;
        HashSet<Integer> generateLotteryNumbers = new HashSet<Integer>
        (capacity);
        Random r = new Random();

        do    {
        int next = r.nextInt(50);
        if(!generateLotteryNumbers.contains(r.nextInt(50)));    {
            generateLotteryNumbers.add(next);
            capacity--;

        }
                while (capacity > 0);
        {
                generateLotteryNumbers.stream().forEach(n-
                >System.out.println(n));
    }
```

Comment: you wrote the while without closing the correct brackets...

Comment: What you've posted doesn't compile.  Please post your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

There were few syntax errors; missing curly bracket around the do (you only closed the if) missing braces at the end, and -> was split across two lines.

Also you had a ; after the if condition...

I've reformatted the code which makes things clearer.

```
public class LotteryNumberGenerator {
    public static <generateLotteryNumbers> void main(String[] args) {

        int capacity = 6;
        HashSet<Integer> generateLotteryNumbers = new HashSet<Integer>(capacity);
        Random r = new Random();

        do {
            int next = r.nextInt(50);
            if (!generateLotteryNumbers.contains(r.nextInt(50))) {
                generateLotteryNumbers.add(next);
                capacity--;

            }
        } while (capacity > 0);
        generateLotteryNumbers.stream().forEach(n -> System.out.println(n));
    }
}
```

The real source of the problem however is the repeated use of `r.nextInt(50)`. The 2nd call is very unlikely to produce the same number. It should be like this...

```
int next = r.nextInt(50);
if (!generateLotteryNumbers.contains(next)) {
```

as AFSW points out, an alternative would to be use the boolean return from the add() method

```
if (generateLotteryNumbers.add(r.nextInt(50))) {
    capacity--;
}
```

My alternative would to be not to try to maintain the capacity yourself, just use the built in size() method. Thus

```
do {
    generateLotteryNumbers.add(r.nextInt(50));
} while (generateLotteryNumbers.size() < capacity);
```

Comment: There is a minor problem in the code. You create a random number `next`, but then check whether another random number is contained in the set `generateLotteryNumbers`.

Comment: People always forget that `add` returns a boolean value...The obvious way would be to write `if (generateLotteryNumbers.add(r.nextInt(50)) {
                capacity--;
            }`

Comment: Thanks all. I'm sorted

Comment: @Wim If this answer solves your problem please consider accepting it https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers